# How to set the original option for picker view?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have a UILabel that display 3 options which is walk, run, and swim. I have a corresponding picker view that displays these 3 options for users to choose when the users tap the UILabel. The default option for the UILabel is depend on what the users choose last time. I want the picker view to show the correct option when it is showed first time.

it seems there is no delegate method for picker view to do that.

Comment: you can use [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The default option for the UILabel is depend on what the users choose
>   last time.

Then, you need to save the value within the App by using the `NSUserDefaults`.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    [[NSUserDefaults StandardDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row] objectForkey:@"selcetdRow"]
}
```

in the ViewDidLoad , just call this

```
 [picker selectRow:[[NSUserDefaults StandardDefaults] objectForkey:@"selcetdRow"]intValue] inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```